# VSTO Word Editor doesn't see mailItem bookmarks

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, bookmarks, mailitem

I am creating Outlook Add-in which adds a footer to mail after button is pushed.

I have a problem with bookmarks '_MailAutoSig' and '_MailOriginal' which are showed in mailItem.HtmlBody (it contains '' and ' tags), but while i open Mail in WordEditor thers is no Bookmarks at all.

i use following cote to read content of email:

```
private void logHtml_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("mailItem");
    log.Info(GetMailItem(e).HTMLBody);
}

private void logWord_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("WordDoc");
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;

    mailItem = GetMailItem(e);

    if (mailItem != null)
    {
        Word.Document doc = mailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;

        Word.Bookmarks bookmarks = doc.Content.Bookmarks;
        foreach (var bookmark in bookmarks)
        {
            log.Debug(bookmark.ToString());
        }
        log.Debug(doc.Bookmarks);
        log.Debug(doc.Content.Text);
    }
}
```

could you tell me if i'm doing something wrong or what i should do to load mailItem with bookmarks to Word.Document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find that in Outlook Bookmarks window there is show hidden option which needs to be checked to see MailOriginal and MailAutoSig bookmarks.

Similarly in Add-in i needed to add `doc.Bookmarks.ShowHidden = true;` before getting list of bookmarks to see those 2 hidden bookmarks.

After adding that line all is showing properly.

Comment: Hi I am facing the same problem. The two bookmarks just don't appear. Can you let me know where in the code did you add this line please?